# Sending mail via amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, email

I trying to send an email though amazon AWS

I have confirmed that I am able to send a email through postie like this:

postie.exe -host:email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com -port:587 -ssl -tls -esmtp -to:barn.fleischer@gmail.com -from:barn.fleischer@gmail.com -s:"testmail" -msg:"This is a test" -user:XXXX -pass:YYYY

But when I try to send via System.Net.Mail

```
  <mailSettings>
  <smtp from="barn.fleischer@gmail.com">
    <network host="email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
     port="587"
     userName="XXXX"
     password="YYYY"
     enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>   
</mailSettings>


Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. 
---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Any suggestions?

Erik

Comment: disable SSL and try on port 25 as a sanity check

Comment: Same error message.

However.. It works when I run it on my local machine, but fails when it is runned from the server.

Comment: Have you checked outgoing Windows firewall settings on that server?

Comment: It WAS a firewall issue, it took a while for out network guy to confirm that.

Comment: Good news! I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked outgoing Windows firewall settings on that server? Make sure you have opened all standard ports eg 25 465 587 etc.